# Scientific `d` notation not read in C++

Tags: c++, fortran, scientific-notation, data-files

I need to read a data file in which numbers are written in a format like this:

```
1.0d-05
```

C++ doesn't seem to recognize this type of scientific notation! Any ideas on how I could read/convert those types of numbers?

I need numbers (i.e. `double` / `float`) not strings. Maybe there is already a class / header to manage this format, but I could not find it.

Comment: Write your own parser?

Comment: The C preprocessor isn't even meant to do this?!?

Comment: Or just replace the `d` with an `e`...

Comment: is 1.0d-05 the same as 1.0e-05 ?

Comment: if fixing the fortan is an option, you can readily change to good old E format

Answer (score 5):

Files produced by Fortran programs report [double precision numbers (in scientific notation)](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-4.html#sh-4.5) using the letter D instead of E.

So your options are:

1. Preprocess the Fortran data file (a simple *Search and Replace* is enough).
2. Use something like:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>

   int main()
   {
     std::istringstream input("+1.234000D-5 -2.345600D+0 +3.456700D-2");

     std::vector<double> result;

     std::string s;
     while (input >> s)
     {
       auto e(s.find_first_of("Dd"));
       if (e != std::string::npos)
         s[e] = 'E';

       result.push_back(std::stod(s));
     }

     for (auto d : result)
       std::cout << std::fixed << d << std::endl;

     return 0;
   }
   ```

Also:

- take a look at [Reading ASCII numbers using "D" instead of "E" for scientific notation using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555097/reading-ascii-numbers-using-d-instead-of-e-for-scientific-notation-using-c) (it's C but you get the idea);
- double check the input file since Fortran can drop the 'E' / 'D' (see [For three digit exponents Fortran drops the 'E' in the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004824/for-three-digit-exponents-fortran-drops-the-e-in-the-output) and [How to read FORTRAN formatted numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520464/how-to-read-fortran-formatted-numbers-in-c)).